# Math formula deleted: Insufficient extension fonts error

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm using this [simplified friggeri CV](https://github.com/eklenske/CV) in which a the author define a new environnment in a `.cls` file as follows :

```
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%                                                  
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{2cm}l}
}{%                 
  \end{tabular*} 
}
```

then use it in `.tex` like this :

```
\begin{entrylist}
...
\end{entrylist}
```

But at compilation with pdflatex I get the following error :

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/stmry/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 73.

./k-cv.tex:89: Math formula deleted: Insufficient extension fonts.
\endtabular* ->\crcr \egroup \egroup $
                                      \egroup 
l.89 \end{entrylist}
```

I can't figure out what this snippet has to do with Math symbol. Do I need to import anything ?

Edit :

For some reasons on my laptop, pdflatex used with sudo works as it should. Is there any reason for calling sudo to make pdflatex work ?

Comment: tabular use math internally to get vertical centering so presumably any math mode will give the same, please try to make a small self contained example that shows the problem

Comment: I get no error. You probably have an incomplete TeX distribution without the StMaryRd fonts.

Comment: Indeed, I popped a vm and install texlive within and everything's fine. I didn't even have to install stmaryfonts. I'll try on my laptop and see what's going on.

Comment: Since you say that sudo works (which shouldn't be necessary), I suspect your user lacks reading privileges on the files/fonts needed. Or the file database for the user is not updated.

Comment: Since I installed it as root, what could lead to error with user rights ?